# C++ - insert into std::map directly without assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, stdmap

I have a `std::map` that I would like to insert an object into, but I would like to avoid unnecessary copies, since it is a large object, and copies take time.
I tried this:

```
MyPODType data(otherData);
data.modify();
myMap["Some key"] = data;
```

However this requires 2 copies: one to copy the `otherData`, and one in the assignment operator to insert the object. Since it's POD, the copy constructor and assignment operator are both the default.

How can I do this with only 1 copy? I realize some compilers will optimize out the second copy but I'd like to do this in a portable way.

Comment: `myMap.emplace("Some key", otherData).first->second.modify();`

Comment: Thank you! `emplace` looks like it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5):

(I am assuming `MyPODType` is the exact `value_type` of your `map`)

As pointed out by Igor Tandetnik in comments, since C++11 you can write:

```
myMap.emplace("Some key", otherData);
```

and then you can call `modify()` on the value while it is in the map.

The `emplace` function will use *perfect forwarding* to forward your arguments to the constructor of the key and value respectively, instead of having to create a temporary `std::pair` or default-construct a value.

It's also possible to use `insert`:

```
std::pair<KeyType, MyPODType> p = { "Some key ", otherData };
p.second.modify();
myMap.insert( std::move(p) );
```

although the `emplace` option seems simpler.